# Type checking for Vectors in Idris

Tags: idris

From REPL how does not ensures that the a list is indeed interpret as a vector instead?

For example if I type:

```
:t Vect
```

I get `Vect : Nat -> Type -> Type` which makes absolute sense, if I type

```
:t Vect 2
```

I get `Vect : Type -> Type` which makes again absolute sense. But I try now:

```
:t Vect 2 [1,2]
```

and get an error

```
Can't disambiguate since no name has a suitable type: 
         Prelude.List.::, Prelude.Stream.::, Data.Vect.::
```

I was hoping to see instead `[1,2] : Vect 2 Int` instead. What I am doing wrong? I also have issues when using the function `the` when trying to interpret a list as vector.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the : (a : Type) -> a -> a` takes a type and a value of that type and returns that value. So if the target type cannot be inferred from context, like in the REPL, you can use `the (Vect 2 Int) [1,2]` to specify what you mean with `[1,2]`.

(`Vect 2 [1,2]` tries to use the `List`, `Stream` or `Vect` `[1,2]` as the argument in `Vect 2 : Type -> Type`. But unlike e.g. `Int`, the list `[1,2]` is not a `Type`, so that throws you that error.)